Failed to install Noetic on Windows
I found this weird error when trying to install Noetic on Windows recently. It seems Nuget can't find the package based on the error message.
I can't find similar issues on the board. Does anyone know how to fix this? Your help is appreciated.
(Unfortunately I have to stay on Noetic due to working on some legacy code.)


From
https://github.com/ms-iot/ROSOnWindows/issues/450#issuecomment-1887797265

Microsoft is no longer providing independent ROS releases and recommends using the binary distributions from Open Robotics.

I wonder if that means there are no longer official Noetic binaries for Windows?
You could try Robostack https://robostack.github.io/GettingStarted.html
That doesn't currently work for me either, but you might give it a try with a clean installation.
